# how to echo one by one in loop on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

I am writing a program that send bulk email to our registered users via ajax.

I want echo every loop response when it is completed and it goes to next condition.

For Example:-

I have list of 100 Emails in database. When i submitted the request to program it will start sending emails.

Prog. works something like :

```
<?php
       foreach($emails as $email){
          $status = $this->sendMail($email);
          if($status == true)
          {
            echo "Mail Sent";
          }else{
            echo "Not Sent";
          }
       }
?>
```

Now i want to print "Mail Sent"/"Not Sent" again and again for every loop.

**Output:-**

Mail Sent

Mail Sent

Mail Sent

Not Sent

Mail Sent

Sending..

**EDIT**

My PHP Code is:-

```
<?php


    public function send_message() {
        $sendTo = $this->input->post('send_to');
        $template = $this->input->post('template');
        $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
        switch ($sendTo) {
            case 1:
                $users = $this->getAllEmails();
                break;
            case 2:
                $users = $this->getRegisteredUsersEmails();
                break;
            case 3:
                $users = $this->getTemproryUsersEmails();
                break;
            case 4:
                $users = $this->getSubscribersEmails();
                break;
        }
        $status = $this->sendMail($users, $template, $subject);
        echo "Mail Sent";
    }
 private function sendMail($users, $template, $subject) {
        $this->load->library('parser');
        $status = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $message = $this->parser->parse('email_templates/' . $template, array('email' => $user->email, 'name' => ($user->name != '') ? "Hi " . $user->name : "Hello"), TRUE);
            $response = $this->mail->send(config_item('sender_mail'), config_item('sender_name'), $user->email, $subject, $message);
            $status[$i]['email'] = $user->email;
            $status[$i]['status'] = ($response == 1) ? 1 : 0;
            $i++;
        }
        return $status;
    }
?>
```

My Ajax Code :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#send_mail").submit(function(){
    $.ajax{
    url:"<?php echo base_url('promotion/send_message'); ?>",
    type:"post",
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success:function(data){
       $("#status").html(data);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: When I submit request via ajax it will return the complete response after sending email to all. Not for every loop. I want response for when every loop runs.

Comment: You are not getting what i am saying @Anant

Think when i submit a ajax to porg. it will start sending email in loop and after completing the process it will send all the "Mail Send/Not Send" Response in "success:function(data)" at once. 

I want when email 1 sent show it prints "Mail Sent" and goes to next and sent next and then print "Mail Sent" one by one not at once.

Comment: create a jquery mail-id array first then :- `$.each(mailid, function() { $.ajax({....your code and in this code alert(response)})});`

Comment: All Mail id are fetched from the database by the program. I have to only click on send button..

your jquery works on user provided email list.

Comment: hey man my code will send `ajax` request for each `mail id`, and you can make a jquery `mail-ids array` through your `php` returned value via `db`.

Comment: please provide code with your ajax and db result form

Comment: @DavidJawphan I have added my code in my question please check...

Comment: do you want to check that status on ajax response ? or not where ?

Comment: I want to print the response when each time "$this->mail->send" function is called in "sendMail()". @DavidJawphan

Answer (score 2):

You have to do your loop with javascript/jquery rather than PHP. To have no overflow on server-side you should probably only call the function on success by using recursion. This way it will be synchronous.

**jQuery**

```
var emails = [
'lorem@stackoverflow.com', 
'ipsum@stackoverflow.com', 
'foo@stackoverflow.com'
];

index = 0;
var sendMail = function(email){
  $.ajax({
    url:"sendMail.php",
    type: "POST"
    data: { emailId: email}  
    success:function(response) {
        index++;
        document.write(response); 
        if(emails[index] != undefined){
            sendMail(emails[index]);
        }
     }
  });
}

sendMail(emails[index]);
```

**PHP**

```
$status = $this->sendMail($$_POST['email']);
$msg = $status ? "Mail Sent" : "Not Sent";
echo $msg;
```

Comment: I dont submit emails list from the form. I just only have "Start Sending Emails" on page when i click on that button ajax call runs and send the request to prog. that will fetch emails from the database and send the emails.. @Horst

Comment: you would still follow the same rule. send request, fetch email, send email, respond, next ajax request.

Comment: Server will get hanged on bulk request.

Comment: Do not loop and start ajax requests. Use recursion and only start next request on success. This way it will be synchronous and won't overflow.

Comment: I think you are near to solve my problem.
I am bit confused with your php code what is "getEmailById" and in ajax request "data: { emailId: id}" how email is passed. you passed index "sendMail(index);" so id will become 0,1,2.....n

As per your code i need to make emails JavaScript Array on page where my "send" button. Right

If Yes The issue causes when i have more then 1 lack email.

Comment: You won't send the index, but the value at the index of the mailIds array. I did that because you said you will fetch emails from database. Of course you can change the mailIds array to an array with actual emails. Really not that hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

`I want to print the response when each time "$this->mail->send" function is called in "sendMail()"`

As your code above, `$status` should be return in ajax function like a json object array.so I try this one ...

```
private function sendMail($users, $template, $subject) {
    $this->load->library('parser');
    $status = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $message = $this->parser->parse('email_templates/' . $template, array('email' => $user->email, 'name' => ($user->name != '') ? "Hi " . $user->name : "Hello"), TRUE);
        $response = $this->mail->send(config_item('sender_mail'), config_item('sender_name'), $user->email, $subject, $message);
        $status[$i]['email'] = $user->email;
        $status[$i]['status'] = ($response == 1) ? 1 : 0;
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($status);
}
```

Ajax Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#send_mail").submit(function(){
$.ajax{
url:"<?php echo base_url('promotion/send_message'); ?>",
type:"post",
dataType : "json",
data:$(this).serialize(),
success:function(data){
    $.each(data,function(i,v){
       $("#status").append(v.status);
     }
}
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: This will returns the result after sending mail to the complete list. I want to print Result one by one. When mail sent to one email then it print the response and when mail sent to another id then print next response.

Comment: your sendMail() is written for all mail i think,if you want to do one by one change that `sendMail` function for only one user name and return only one will be more better

Comment: You're right. but for doing this i have to fetch all email before clicking on "send mail" button and pass each email address through the ajax.  It causes server issue because if i have more then 1 lack emails so program will send more then 1 lack ajax request.